# Crear un formulario con un array de Entry inputs en Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Estoy empezando con Xamarin.forms y me ha surgido la necesidad de crear una lista con varios `Entry inputs`.

La idea es hacer algo como esto:

[image: Ejemplo Xamarin.forms]

Y cuando pinche en el botón nuevo se cree otra fila, que a su vez se pueda eliminar, para añadir nuevos datos.

Este es el XAML que uso:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid Padding="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Entry Placeholder="Edad" />
        <Picker Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Gender" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Hombre</x:String>
                <x:String>Mujer</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>
        <Entry Grid.Column="2" Placeholder="Nombre" />
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Text="Nuevo" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Finalmente, cuando pinche en el botón "Generar" se parsee un JSON para enviar a un API Rest mas o menos así:

```
[{
  edad: "24",
  genero: "mujer",
  nombre: "Celia"
}, {
  edad: "30",
  genero: "hombre",
  nombre: "Daniel"
}]
```

¿De que forma podría hacer esto?

Comment: Creo que deberias hacer distinto. Denerias tener 3 entry fijos y cuando vas agregando esos datos se pasan a tu ListView. en lugar de crear en cada fila tus 3 entry

Comment: Pero eso ya no me permitiría editar un nombre que ya haya añadido, ¿no? ¿No es posible crear un listview con los 3 entry?

Comment: Claro que es posible, y si podes editar el nombre que hayas añadido cuando toques la fila que desees, esa info la podes colocar en tu Entry nuevamente y modificarla, pero sera menos complicado hacer comprobaciones y no crearas componentes mas pesados que el label para mostrar tu info.

Comment: Claro, podría editarlo volviendo a cargar los datos en el Entry, pero tengo la necesidad de que predomine el UX y hacer algo parecido a lo que hace Google Keep cuando añades una "Nueva lista". Si no consigo lo que quiero entonces veré la forma de hacerlo como me has sugerido. Gracias!!

Comment: Si podes hacerlo como queres.

Comment: resolviste tu problema?

Comment: Que va, no consigo montar el ItemsSource con los Entry